# Unable to require a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am currently in the process of extracting modules from a monolithic React project so that they can be stored separately in my npm registry, but I can't seem to export and import them properly.  Before trying to extract them, I was using:

```
const Component = require("./component.js");
```

and using webpack to bundle everything.  That was working fine.  I then moved the component to a separate project, which I bundled with webpack.  I can't seem to get it to work as an npm dependency however.  Here's the basic code for the component:

```
// Some require statements
...
var Component = React.createClass({...});
module.exports = Component;
```

The build process outputs the bundle to build/bundle.js, and the package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "component",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "description": "...",
  "main": "build/bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build-dev": "webpack",
    "build-min": "NODE_ENV=production webpack && uglifyjs ./build/bundle.js -c -m -o ./build/bundle.min.js --source-map ./build/bundle.min.js.map",
    "prepublish": "npm run build-min"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "registry"
  },
  "author": "esaron",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

And I'm importing it with:

```
const Component = require("component");
```

When I try to load the page, I see the following error in the console:

> bundle.js:1299 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `exports`.

And when debugging, sure enough, the call to require is giving me

> Component = Object {}

I get the same results if I require the bundle.js directly after copying it into the project, so I feel like I must just not be setting up my build and publish the right way, and after searching for a while, I wasn't able to find out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be bundling your components when they are separated out into their own packages. If they are using ES6, it's a good idea to transpile them using Babel as a prepublish step, but you do not need to bundle them.

Think about what the bundle step is doing to your component. It is going through your entry point and pulling in any required dependencies into a single file. That means that your bundle.js result will have pulled in all of react, react-dom, and anything else you required from your component.

Only your main application (which will be requiring the component packages) needs a bundle step. Here, it will resolve all dependencies including those that are nested and pull them together into your app's bundle.js, ensuring that you do not end up with duplicate copies of libraries like react pulled into your app.

Comment: I wasn't thinking this through at all.  Thanks!